# Regex to parse Product Size (Count, Pack size) from string

Tags: python, regex

I have a long list of strings that are different products in my database, each with a product label and product sizes (including packaging size) of the product. The product label is slightly variable and I want a regex to account for all those: I want the regex to split the strings into 3 substrings: 1. Parse out a string if the label has "Pack" or "pck" or "Count" 2. Parse out the size--12, 24, etc 3. The size of each pack (12.5 oz, 10-oz). I have the following strings for example:

```
str1 = "Greenies Original Regular Natural Dental Dog Treats, 12 oz. Pack (12 Treats)"

str2 = "Greenies Pill Pockets Capsule Size Dog Treats Chicken Flavor, 7.9 oz. Pack (30 Treats)"

str3 = "Blue Buffalo Family Favorites Natural Adult Wet Dog Food, Sunday Chicken 12.5-oz can (Pack of 12)"

str4 = "Blue Buffalo Dental Bones Natural Adult Dental Chew Regular Dog Treat, 12-oz bag (12 Count)" 

str5 = "Purina ONE Natural Dry Dog Food, SmartBlend Chicken & Rice Formula - 8 lb. Bag"

str6 = "Rachael Ray Nutrish Natural Dry Dog Food, Real Chicken & Veggies Recipe, 14 lbs"

str7 = "(12 Pack) Purina ALPO Gravy Wet Dog Food, Gravy Cravers Roast Beef Flavor in Gravy, 13.2 oz. Cans"

str8 = "Ol' Roy Munchy Bones Dog Treats, Greek Yogurt Flavor, 20 ounce, 7 Count"
```

What I would like to get is:

```
str1_group = ['12 oz', 'Pack', '12 Treats']

str2_group = ['7.9 oz', 'Pack', '30 Treats']

str3_group = ['12.5-oz', 'can', '12 Count']

str4_group = ['12-oz', 'bag', '12 Count']

str5_group = ['8 lb', 'Bag', '']

str6_group = ['14 lbs', '', '']

str7_group = ['13.2 oz', 'Cans', '12 Pack']

str8_group = ['20 ounce', '', '7 Count']
```

The challenge here is that a lot of products have different descriptions: some have Pack details at the start of string and some at the end, some have weight details in oz., Ounces and some have lbs.

What I have tried:

```
re.search(r'(\d+(\.\d+)?\s[ol]?[zbs])', text)
```

However, the above is only accounting fro "12 oz" "12.5 oz" "0.5 oz" **(Not even "12.5-oz")** types of string. It is getting a little challenging for me to write the best regex to account for every scenario.

Can someone please help me with the best regex to solve this issues? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Your string formats are far from being standardized... there's no consistency between them.  I'm not entirely sure you can have one single regex that can extract the values from all of them.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Can I add multiple regex using a condition in Python?

Comment: You can use multiple regex, but the problem then becomes how do you tell the script to use which regex on which string?

Comment: One way you can do is have a specific regex for the size, product unit, and packaging counts.  But that would mean you need to know the unit/count types before hand, and need to know all variations in your string.

Comment: Hmm yeah that seems difficult :(. Thank you for this though!

Comment: @Thefourthbird I thought of that too, but that patterns fall short on `str7` (12 Pack).

Comment: @r.ook Oh my, I see. I will remove the comment.

Comment: This would get you a few more empty matches, but I think it will get all the data from the examples https://ideone.com/GimYEo

Comment: This seems like a complex task, it might be possible to do this in regex, depending on how varied the sizes are.